# I can't access the Amazon.ca when I click any button on the homepage as it keeps redirecting to Amazon.com. How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: browser, opera

When I'm navigating the Amazon.ca website and attempt to interact with any clickable element, I get an automatic redirection to Amazon.com.

[image]